# How do I close a tkinter mainloop by pressing some keyboard key

Tags: python, tkinter, keyboard

I would like to ask about two related issues. The main one:

I want to open an entry, type some text, and then I want the program to resume when I press the Enter key.

However, the only solution I've found to shot down tk mainloop is adding an 'ok' buttom which I most click on.

As the idea is to use the quick pop up window to retrive some information and move one, the clicking requirement is very unfortunate.

The second issue is:

I would like the entry box to pop up in front of everything else on my screen... is that possible? I'm pretty new on programming so I haven't look into the second issue. I use Jupyter notebook to run this code, I don't know if I should compile my code for it to better interact with the user's interface.

Thanks!

```
master = tkinter.Tk()
e = tkinter.Entry(master)
e.pack()
def callback():
    global fa
    fa=e.get() # This is the text you may want to use later
    master.destroy()
b = tkinter.Button(master, text = "OK", width = 10, command = callback)
master.mainloop()
```

No error in that code. Global variable 'fa' is created and then the mainloop is 'destroyed'. The problem, as said, is that it requires the user to click on the ok buttom

Comment: You can "bind" a function to a specific keyboard event. See [Events: responding to stimuli](http://web.archive.org/web/20190205150959id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/events.html),

Comment: _"I want to open an entry, type some text, and then I want the main loop to resume"_ - this doesn't make sense. mainloop has to be running for you to be able to type. If it's not running, tkinter can't process the keyboard events.

Comment: Bryan Oakley you're right, when I said main loop I meant the remaining code that should run after mainloop stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just some basic tkinter binding. When you press an arrow key, the triangle moves. Hope this helps.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Canvas

tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_polygon(10, 10, 10, 60, 50, 35, fill='blue')  # This is the triangle


def movetriangle(event):
    if event.keysym == 'Up':
        canvas.move(1, 0, -3)
    elif event.keysym == 'Down':
        canvas.move(1, 0, 3)
    elif event.keysym == 'Left':
        canvas.move(1, -3, 0)
    elif event.keysym == 'Right':
        canvas.move(1, 3, 0)
canvas.bind_all('<Key>', movetriangle)
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: It work, thanks!, would you know how to make that 'entry' window to open on top of everything? I run the entire code while changing windows and I would like that this part would trigger a box on top of everything so I can access it quickly. I think this is not possible using jupyter notebook...